# how to cluster a time series data having different sizes of vectors in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am interested in clustering time-series data that I have into 6 groups. the data that I have represents each row as a single time-series data and like this, I have some 800 to 1000 time-series data. but each time series data is of different lengths, for instance, time-series data '1' has 102 values; time-series data '2' has 56 values; time-series data '3' has 180 values and so on.... the sample data that I have in excel is shown as follows:

```
  A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J    K    L    M    N    O    P    Q    R    S    T
1 7.4  8.1  8.5  9.1  9.6  10.2 10.7 11.3 11.9
2 7.3  7.6  7.9  8.2  8.5  8.8  9.1  9.4  9.7  10.1 10.4 10.7 11.5
3 7.6  8.1  8.6  9.1  9.6  10.2 10.7 11.8
4 7.4  7.8  8.4  8.9  9.4  10.0 10.5 11.1 11.6 12.3 12.8 13.4 13.5 13.9 14.4 14.9 15.4
```

I am unaware of handling the unequal length of time-series data for clustering

how to calculate dtw between two time-series data.

for the time series data having equal lengths, it is working with the code as follows

```
library(dtw)

dm <- dist(sample1, method= "DTW")
hc <- hclust(dm, method="average")

 plot(hc, labels=Labels, 
 cex = 0.5, 
 hang = -1, 
 col = 'blue',
 main="cluster dendrogram")

rect.hclust(hc, k = 6) # displays the groups in the plot
```

is there any way to to make all the time-series that I have into equal lengths. because if the time-series data are not in equal length, calculating Euclidean distances/ dtw, calculating any other feature etc is not possible.

I am looking for code and approach in detail to handle such kind of data

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Using the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, we can fit each to a straight line and then cluster the slopes.

```
library(Ckmeans.1d.dp) # univariate clustering package

slopes <- coef(lm(t(DF) ~ seq_along(DF)))[2, ]
fm <- Ckmeans.1d.dp(slopes)

# graph the slopes on X axis identifying each and
# coloring each cluster with a different color
plot(fm)
text(slopes, 1, 1:4, adj = 0:-1)
```

[continued after plot]

[image: screenshot]

```
library(zoo)

# plot each series with each cluster having a different color
plot(zoo(t(DF)), screen = 1, col = fm$cluster)
```

[continued after plot]

[image: screenshot]

### Note

Input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "row A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J    K    L    M    N    O    P    Q    R    S    T
1 7.4  8.1  8.5  9.1  9.6  10.2 10.7 11.3 11.9
2 7.3  7.6  7.9  8.2  8.5  8.8  9.1  9.4  9.7  10.1 10.4 10.7 11.5
3 7.6  8.1  8.6  9.1  9.6  10.2 10.7 11.8
4 7.4  7.8  8.4  8.9  9.4  10.0 10.5 11.1 11.6 12.3 12.8 13.4 13.5 13.9 14.4 14.9 15.4"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)[-1]
```

Comment: can you please explain me in detail what the syntax is doing. i have a large set of time series data of unequal length like this (each row*n columns is one data point/time series data). can we cluster the data using the presented approach?  thanks in advance

Comment: when i test the code with my data having 33 time-series with variable lengths, i am getting the following error ... Error in model.frame.default(formula = t(asqw1) ~ seq_along(asqw1), drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'seq_along(asqw1)').... what should be the value in the (starred) syntax: slopes1 <- coef(lm(t(asqw1) ~ seq_along(asqw1)))[**2**, ] ??

Comment: Reduce this down to a minimal reproducible example and show it.

Comment: i have presented the problem as an answer please look at it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200562/discussion-between-kumar-and-g-grothendieck).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about how to cluster time series, but I tried the method provided in the OP's example on unequal length time series and it seems to work fine... and it should: according to the authors of the `dtw` package,

> The function performs Dynamic Time Warp (DTW) and computes the optimal alignment between two time series x and y, given as numeric vectors. The "optimal" alignment minimizes the sum of distances between aligned elements. **Lengths of x and y may differ**.

First load the libraries

```
library(dtw); library(ggplot2)
```

then create the time series

```
xlist <- list(x1 = c(7.4, 8.1, 8.5, 9.1, 9.6, 10.2, 10.7, 11.3, 11.9)
              x2 = c(7.3, 7.6, 7.9, 8.2, 8.5, 8.8, 9.1, 9.4, 9.7, 10.1,
                     10.4, 10.7, 11.5)
              x3 = c(7.6, 8.1, 8.6, 9.1, 9.6, 10.2, 10.7, 11.8)
              x4 = c(7.4, 7.8, 8.4, 8.9, 9.4, 10, 10.5, 11.1, 11.6, 12.3,
                     12.8, 13.4, 13.5, 13.9, 14.4, 14.9, 15.4))
```

... that look like this

```
df <- stack(xlist)
df$i <- unlist(lapply(xlist, seq_along))

ggplot(df, aes(i, values, color = ind)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + theme_bw() + facet_wrap(.~ind, nrow = 2) + 
  labs(x="", y="", color = "Time series")
```

[image: Time series with ggplot]

The same code as the one used by the OP on equal length time series seems to work fine.

```
dm <- dist(xlist, method= "DTW")
hc <- hclust(dm, method="average")

plot(as.dendrogram(hc), hang = -1)
rect.hclust(hc, k = 2)
```

[image: Dendrogram]

Answer (score 0):

you could potentially try and discover motifs in the time series as a means of finding similarity, i.e. find shorter segments of the time series that are similar, and not similarity based on the entire length of time series. However, without some insight into the domain, problem at hand etc. it is hard to determine if that is suitable.

[Symbolic Aggregate approXimation (SAX)](https://github.com/jMotif/jmotif-R) based clustering algorithms allow for this.